# TensorFlow - How to minimize function of one variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been given a fully trained model by another researcher that has inputs as placeholders. Regarding it as a function `f(x)`, I would like to find `x` to minimize my distance metric (loss function) `dist(x, f(x))`. This could be something like the euclidean distance between the two points.

I tried to use TensorFlow's built-in optimizer functions. The issue is that `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss, var_list[input_placeholder])` fails, complaining that `input_placeholder` isn't of a supported type. Thus, I cannot get gradients for my input.

How can I optimize a function in TensorFlow when the inputs have to be specified in this way? Unfortunately, these placeholders are not passed through a `Variable` first, and I have to treat that model as a black box.

Comment: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918795/minimize-a-function-of-one-variable-in-tensorflow) related question, but it uses a `Variable` to store the input to optimize. If I could feed a `Variable` into a placeholder, I could do what the answer there does.

Comment: Isn't `d(x - f(x))` `1 - df(x)`?

Comment: No, sorry, `d` is some distance function, not the differentiation operator. I'll update my question to make that clear

Answer (score 0):

Using the Keras functional API detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41052363/2137996), I created a dense layer with no bias to sit right before the model I was given. Holding its input as a constant all 1's vector, I optimized the joined model using only the `Variable` in the dense layer, giving me the optimal vector as the *output* of that layer.

All TensorFlow `Optimizer` subclasses allow you to `minimize` while only modifying a particular set of `Variables`, which I got out of Keras fairly simply.

Comment: If someone knows of a better solution, please let me know. It might also be worth adding something like a "Constant" layer to Keras to enable doing something like this more easily.