# Tensorflow TensorShape error on concatenating two models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to the functional API. I'm trying to concatenate two models into one to take one output like this:

```
cnn_model = Input(shape=(49, 10))
x = Conv1D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(cnn_model)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')

mlp_model = Input(shape=(4,))
y = Dense(64, activation='relu')(mlp_model)
y = Dense(32, activation='relu')(y)

combined = Concatenate()([x, y])

z = Dense(16, activation='relu')(combined)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(z)

model = Model(inputs=[cnn_model, mlp_model], outputs=output)
```

This raises not defined on an unknown TensorShape error on here

```
combined = Concatenate()([x, y])
```

Error:

> ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

Comment: You can use more flexible model subclass technique, also following link can be helpful..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045729/combine-to-keras-functional-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are encountering the error is because you are trying to concentrate a `Dense` object and a `KerasTensor`. You forgot to pass the `x` Tensor from the `Flatten` layer to the following `Dense` layer.

You need to change this line:

```
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')
```

with the following:

```
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
```